# Thousand separator and comma in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, decimal

I'm trying to rapresent a number like: 10.000,20 in this way:

```
{{item.value | number:2}}
```

but the result is not what I expected:

10000.2

What is wrong? How can I add both thousand separator and decimal comma?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
app.filter('toLocaleDecimal', ($filter) => {
  return function(input) {
    let number = Number(input);
    if (number && !Number.isNaN(number)) {
      return Number(number).toLocaleString('desired_locale');
    } else {
      return '00,00';
    }
  }
});
```

HTML: `{{item.value | toLocaleDecimal}}`